# Sql to Linq query

Tags: linq-to-entities

Please let me know how will i make Linq query out of it.

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[K1] AS [AccountName], 

[GroupBy1].[K2] AS [LeadBy], 

[GroupBy1].[K3] AS [Status], 

[GroupBy1].[K3] AS [Industry], 

[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]

FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[AccountName] AS [K1],

     [Extent2].[LeadBY] AS [K2],

     [Extent2].[Status] AS [K3],

     [Extent2].[Industry] AS [K4],

    COUNT(1) AS [A1]

    FROM [dbo].[Opportunities] AS [Extent1]

    join [dbo].[Leads] AS [Extent2]

    on [Extent1].[AccountName] IS NOT NULL

    AND [Extent1].[AccountName]=[Extent2].[AccountName]

    GROUP BY [Extent1].[AccountName],[Extent2].[Leadby],[Extent2].[Status],[Extent2].
[Industry]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this program:
http://www.linqpad.net/ It has examples for basic and advance operations. You can also download other tutorials.

Comment: But for this time can u help me out as i require it urgently there are two table Leads and Oppurtunity and I want to get count of Oppurtunities created by Lead

Answer (score 0):

it deppends on your mapping, if you haven't a foreign key to Lead into AccountName column you should try this:

```
from i in Context.Opportunities
join l in Context.Leads on l.AccountName equals i.AccountName
group i by new { i.AccountName, l.LeadBY, l.Status, l.Industry } into g
select new
{
    g.Key.AccountName,
    g.Key.LeadBY,
    g.Key.Status,
    g.Key.Industry,
    Count = g.Count();
}
```

if you have a foreign key to Lead into AccountName column you should try this:

```
from i in Context.Opportunities
group i by new { i.AccountName, l.Lead.LeadBY, l.Lead.Status, l.Lead.Industry } into g
select new
{
    g.Key.AccountName,
    g.Key.LeadBY,
    g.Key.Status,
    g.Key.Industry,
    Count = g.Count();
}
```